# Do these two definitions of hypersurfaces coincide?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces

According to Wikipedia and some other sources, a hypersurface is a manifold of dimension $n-1$ embedded in an ambient space of dimension $n$ which is simple to understand.

Now here https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/C.M.Elliott/DziEll13a.pdf the Definition 2.1 has a different definition of a hypersurface:

Let $k \in \mathbb N \cup\{\infty\}$. $\Gamma \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is called a hypersurface if for each point $x_0 \in \Gamma$ there exists an open set $U \subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ containing $x_0$ and a function $\phi \in C^k(\Gamma)$ with $\nabla \phi \neq 0$ on $\Gamma \cap U$ and such that $$U \cap \Gamma=\{x \in U \,\vert\, \phi(x)=0 \}$$

Does this have a synonymous meaning as the definition from say Wikipedia? If so, how? I don't have any intuition what the latter definition should mean.

Comment: The latter definition means "locally cut out by a single equation"; the two should be equivalent by the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Qiaochu's comment is definitely true, though it is opaque to me what the authors mean by $\Bbb R^\infty$ here; if it is not supposed to mean the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ or some Banach space you do not get an implicit function theorem.

Comment: thanks. what is the benefit of defining it in such way? And what does "locally cut out be a single equation" mean?

Comment: This is how you find them in practice. And it means exactly what your formula does: there's a single function to R, with 0 as a regular value, so that your submanifold is the zero set.